# Connect to SAP C4C Hybris with Python

Tags: python, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to connect to SAP C4C Hybris with Python.
Can somebody suggest me an approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hybris has [Rest API services](https://help.sap.com/viewer/c5613bd3cc9942efb74d017b40eb0892/2005/en-US/18caa4b5c32c4bcf8b38c6260c0f30e8.html). You can use these services in your Pyhton code.

Comment: thanks, can I kindly ask you to pass a bit more details

Answer (score 0):

If you are after C4C, then that is SAP Cloud for Customer rather than SAP Commerce (which used to be Hybris) ... both of which were previously under the SAP Hybris branding.

C4C has OData web services available & that is probably your best approach: https://help.sap.com/viewer/1364b70b9cbb417ea5e2d80e966d4f49/CLOUD/en-US

I imagine there are OData 2.0 libraries for Python out there, but I am not a Python user ....